# x86 - compare numbers and push the result onto the stack

Tags: x86, comparison-operators

I would like to know, how to compare two numbers and push the result (true, false or 1, 0) onto the stack. I know about the `cmp` instruction, but it only sets the flags. I need something that will result in either 1 or 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for one of the [cmov](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc) instruction variants. They each move the value (or not) to a register that you can then push.

Comment: Use the instruction SETcc, where cc is the condition you want to check. For example, after CMP, use SETE, SETNE, SETGE, SETLE, etc.

Comment: `xor eax,eax` / cmp something / `SETcc AL` / `push rax` to materialize a 32 or 64-bit `0` or `1` you can push.  Unfortunately SETcc was designed to only write an 8-bit register or memory; the first ISA extension to fix this is APX, coming in some future CPU, 40 years late but better than nothing...  And it still costs extra code-size for the zero-upper version, they still didn't make that the default (with a REX2 prefix instead of EVEX.)